# Iterating and modifying JSON in Qt

Tags: c++, json, performance, qt

I need to use JSON to transfer high volume data over network and then interpret it in Qt on runtime in high traffic and performance demanding scenario. Basically hundreds or even thousands or more JSON documents would need to be handled of arbitrary sizes and complexity. I am somewhat free in how to do it but I am considering my options carefully and so far I am not content with what they seem to be.

Main concern is lookup and modification speed while conversion from/to JSON is less significant in my context as I can deal with slower intake and or output that would be erratic anyway. But once the data gets through it needs to be readily available.

My options as I see them:

1) Option 1 is to use the JSON support classes in Qt 5 directly. However the drawback is that in order to modify a single value somewhere in the JSON data tree the whole thing needs to be copied and then the JSON created from it again with the modified value. This could be quite costly for a single modification. The QJsonValueRef helps with it to some extent but does not allow to iterate over the whole structure as each object in the structure still needs to be copied.

2) Convert the JSON into QVariantMap (QMap) and use that instead. Except the overhead of the conversion back and forth it suffers from the same problem as 1) since QAssociativeIterable does not return a reference to its items and thus cannot descend into the structure without copying each QVariant first. Basically it allows non-copy iteration in single sub-level of QVariantMap. It might still be better than using Qt's JSON classes directly though but essentially it seems to have the very same limitation as 1).

3) Convert the JSON to my own data structure that would allow descending through the structure and modification of the data without copying any of the values. Each "level" would become an object to which its parents would hold access thus allowing non-copy access to its contents in arbitrary depth. This solution would suffer from the fact that I very likely cannot implement a lookup mechanism for each "level" that is nearly as efficient as Qt's/STL containers. But maybe I can combine the Qt's containers with this approach by storing the children pointers in them with as fast operator== overload as possible...

4) Convert JSON to a flat 2-dimensional data structure such as:

```
Level1/Level2/key : value
Level1/Level2/key2 : value2
Level1/key3 : value3
```

This approach suffers from lots of redundancy in data storage and could be costly in conversions to/from JSON but arguably offers the greatest lookup/modification speed since it does not need to descend into a any data structure. However the cost of this benefit seems far too great to me (redundancy and slow conversion).

I somewhat lean towards the option 3 but maybe there are other options. I would like to hear your thoughts and/or ideas about this problem. Or maybe JSON is not a right tool for data transfer over network in the first place.

Comment: I think, if you can not use json for transfering data - not use. JSON is a text format, and you will have overhead in anyway. But when your work with json Qt classes or QVaraintMap directly don't worry about data copying overhead - both use implicit sharing - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [you look at the Qt source code](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/dev/src/corelib/json) you will realize that Qt json objects are already optimized :

- Reference counted
- Copy on write.
- Basic memory pooling mechanism. Like dynamic arrays, there is a memory capacity bigger than the actual memory size.
- Contiguous memory for data

To iterate over the structure use the `QJsonObject` class. The overhead of

```
QJsonValue QJsonObject::value(const QString & key);
```

is minimal for object types. But as you noted, it creates a new string for string types; it also perform "casting" for numeric values. Note that after parsing further processing\memory overhead is only when you start dealing with `QJsonValue`.

Thus option 1 is not that bad. Option 2 is plain horrible given your conditions. I fail to see any advantage. Option 4 is nightmarish, for the reasons you specified yourself. The kind of work you regret right after making some progress.

If a disciplined use of the Qt json classes is not enough, then move to a more efficient library like [rapidjson](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html).

Advantages :

- the Json is just a big char array with element just being references + type.
- String management : the getstring return the pointer of the string in the json string. Zero allocation. When you insert strings, you can use a version which only refer to the buffer of the existing data or you can allocate the string as Qt does.
- Total control on allocations. **Object assignment is a move operation**. Unless you explicitly ask to copy you are guaranteed to not have any memory allocation\movement. Methods which allocate memory have an explicit document allocator as argument.
- Zero ref counter because of the move design.
- Json Values are evaluated explicitly.

Inconvenients

- Non-intuitive code style. For grown ups only.
- Much easier to insert defects and have buggy code.

It does what your option 3 is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I am debating between option 1 and using rapidjson now. While performance test of the rapidjson seems like a significant plus there is still an outstanding issue of converting the actual values from rapidjson to Qt and back. Hence the performance gain from using rapidjson could be lessened but I cannot guess how big the impact would be. In any case it would be used in relatively confined portion of my code and I could switch between rapidjson and Qt's json APIs relatively easily.

Comment: After further investigation the rapidjson (or any 3rd party JSON parser) is most likely the only option because the overhead of writing/modifying JSON with Qt at the moment is simply huge. Basically on every change the whole document needs to be rebuilt... There is a rumour about support for writing JSON being added in future version but at the moment the JSON support in Qt is considered read-only.

Comment: I use rapidjson and I believe it fits with memory requirements. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a convenience library for ease of JSON lookup and modification. Instead of being Implicitly Shared as in the QJson API, my library is implemented using Explicit Sharing. This makes edition easier at the cost of loosing thready safety. Check it out:

https://github.com/juangburgos/QJsExplicit

You can do something like this:

```
QJsDocument doc;

// create test object
QJsObject testobj = doc.createObject("testobj");
testobj.setAttribute("attr1", "hola mundo");
testobj.setAttribute("attr2", 3.1416);
testobj.setAttribute("attr3", false);

// create test array
QJsArray testarr = doc.createArray("testarr");
testarr.appendValue(2);
testarr.appendValue(4);
testarr.appendValue(6);
testarr.appendValue(8);

// create test array child object
QJsObject arrchildobj = testarr.createObject("whatever");
arrchildobj.setAttribute("xxx", true);
arrchildobj.setAttribute("yyy", 8);
arrchildobj.setAttribute("zzz", 7.8);

// orphan object append to test
QJsObject orphanobj;
orphanobj.setKeyName("orphanobj");
orphanobj.setAttribute("A", 1);
orphanobj.setAttribute("B", 2);
orphanobj.setAttribute("C", 3);
testobj.appendChild(orphanobj);

// edit through shallow copy of the document
QJsDocument doc2 = orphanobj.ownerDocument();
if (doc2.getChildByKey("testarr").isArray())
{
    QJsArray testarr2 = doc2.getChildByKey("testarr").toArray(); 
    testarr2.setValueAt(3, "ocho");                              
}                                                                

// orphan array append to test array
QJsArray orphanarr;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    QJsObject tempObj;
    tempObj.setAttribute("id", i);
    orphanarr.appendObject(tempObj);
}
testarr.appendArray(orphanarr);

QString strJSON = doc.toJson(QJsNode::Indented);
// print original
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(strJSON);
```

which woud create this:

```
{
    "testarr": [
        2,
        4,
        6,
        "ocho",
        {
            "xxx": true,
            "yyy": 8,
            "zzz": 7.7999999999999998
        },
        [
            {
                "id": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            }
        ]
    ],
    "testobj": {
        "attr1": "hola mundo",
        "attr2": 3.1415999999999999,
        "attr3": false,
        "orphanobj": {
            "A": 1,
            "B": 2,
            "C": 3
        }
    }
}
```